# UIButton setImage has no (immediate) effect

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

Consider the following built in assertion:

```swift
button.isSelected = true
button.setImage(nil, for: .selected)
assert(button.image(for: .selected) === nil) 
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this trips with === and ==
```

Why? Am I making an invalid assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623997-setimage):

> **Discussion**
>
> At a minimum, always set an image for the normal state when associating images to a button. If you don’t specify an image for the other states, the button uses the image associated with normal. If you don’t specify an image for the normal state, the button uses a system value.

What may not be immediately clear is that calling:

```
button.setImage(nil, for: .selected)
```

can also be read as: *"did not specify an image for `.selected` state."*

So, the button will use the image from `.normal`.

If you want to **remove** the image when setting the button state to `.selected`:

```
    button.isSelected = true
    button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
    button.setImage(nil, for: .selected)
```

Here is some sample code to play with:

```
class SelectedButtonVC: UIViewController {
    
    let button = UIButton()
    
    var toggles: [UISwitch] = []
    var imgs: [String : UIImage] = [:]
    let titles: [String] = [
        "Normal", "Highlighted", "Selected",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        var promptLabel: UILabel!
        var vSep: UIView!
        var hs: UIStackView!
        
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemBlue, .systemRed, .systemGreen,
        ]
        let states: [UIControl.State] = [
            .normal, .highlighted, .selected,
        ]
        
        let largeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 40, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
        
        for (t, c) in zip(titles, colors) {
            guard let f = t.first?.description else { fatalError() }
            guard let img = UIImage(systemName: "\(f.lowercased()).square.fill", withConfiguration: largeConfig)?.withTintColor(c, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
                fatalError("Could not load system image for \(t.lowercased())")
            }
            imgs[t] = img
        }
        for (t, s) in zip(titles, states) {
            button.setTitle(t, for: s)
            button.setImage(imgs[t], for: s)
        }
        for (c, s) in zip(colors, states) {
            button.setTitleColor(c, for: s)
        }
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        
        promptLabel = UILabel()
        promptLabel.text = "This is a button..."
        stack.addArrangedSubview(promptLabel)
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        stack.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: button)
        
        vSep = UIView()
        vSep.backgroundColor = .gray
        vSep.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0).isActive = true
        stack.addArrangedSubview(vSep)
        
        hs = UIStackView()
        hs.spacing = 8
        hs.alignment = .center
        promptLabel = UILabel()
        promptLabel.text = "Toggle button.isSelected:"
        hs.addArrangedSubview(promptLabel)
        let sw = UISwitch()
        sw.isOn = false
        toggles.append(sw)
        hs.addArrangedSubview(sw)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(hs)
        
        vSep = UIView()
        vSep.backgroundColor = .gray
        vSep.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2.0).isActive = true
        stack.addArrangedSubview(vSep)
        
        stack.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: vSep)
        
        promptLabel = UILabel()
        promptLabel.text = "Toggle button images for states:"
        stack.addArrangedSubview(promptLabel)
        
        titles.forEach { t in
            hs = UIStackView()
            hs.spacing = 8
            hs.alignment = .center
            promptLabel = UILabel()
            promptLabel.text = t
            hs.addArrangedSubview(promptLabel)
            let v = UIImageView(image: imgs[t])
            v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            hs.addArrangedSubview(v)
            let sw = UISwitch()
            sw.isOn = true
            toggles.append(sw)
            hs.addArrangedSubview(sw)
            stack.addArrangedSubview(hs)
        }
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
        ])
        
        toggles.forEach { sw in
            sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(swTapped(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        }
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func swTapped(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        guard let idx = toggles.firstIndex(of: sender) else { return }
        switch idx {
        case 1:
            button.setImage(sender.isOn ? imgs[titles[0]] : nil, for: .normal)
            ()
        case 2:
            button.setImage(sender.isOn ? imgs[titles[1]] : nil, for: .highlighted)
            ()
        case 3:
            button.setImage(sender.isOn ? imgs[titles[2]] : nil, for: .selected)
            ()
        default:
            button.isSelected = sender.isOn
            ()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button.isSelected =", sender.isSelected)
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

When running, toggling the `.isSelected` switch will, as you might guess, set `button.isSelected` to `true` or `false`.

Toggling the button image state switches will either set the image to an image (if On) or set it to `nil` if Off.

Perhaps worth noting...

When a button has:

```
btn.isSelected = true
```

the ***normal*** properties (title, title color, image, etc) are used for the ***highlighted*** state.

This can be seen in the above example code by toggling `.isSelected` to On, and then tapping the button. We no longer see the "Highlighted" title or image.

If that is your intended behavior, great! If not, you may need to re-think your approach.